# Common document library between two SharePoint sites

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, sharepoint, file-sharing, sharepoint-2010

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

Our organization maintains a sharepoint site for our clients, and sometimes we have situations where different clients (with distinct sharepoint sites on the **same** server) are involved in the same project, and maintain duplicate content in their respective document libraries.

For obvious reasons, I was wondering whether or not there was a 'supported' method of linking a common folder between two distinct sites?

I.E site A, and B are distinct sharepoint sites, but would like to have a shared folder to place collaborative content in.

Hopefully this makes sense.  Thank you in advance for the help!

We're running sharepoint 2010.

Comment: Just to clarify, are they two different sites in the same site collection, or two different site collections entirely?

Comment: They are two different sites within the same site collection.  After some research, it looks like "content types -- link to document" is the functionality I'm after...but things are nowhere near clear at this point -- and any further help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like "content types, link to document" was what I was looking for.  [link](http://erichanes2008.blogspot.com/2011/05/adding-document-links-shortcuts-to.html)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like files/folders cannot be "shared" across sites/libraries with full editing functionality, which makes sense as a fail-safe, given that a situation where multiple users  editing the same file concurrently across different sites can get unruly quickly.

One similar functionality that sharepoint does allow for, is for file links to be used to link to the actual data located elsewhere.  In this scenario, though you cannot make direct edits to the file links/pointers, it does allow for visibility of the file(s) in questions accross multiple sites/libraries.  You can actually use this pointers to link to anything with a url.  Using file links, you can still save the document locally and do what you wish.

Here's some information on [content types](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-content-types-and-content-type-publishing-HA101631493.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This video should explain exactly what you are looking to accomplish.
Same thing I was trying to do with my site + subsites that are all part of the same site collection.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TntwRm78b_4

Comment: Welcome on Serverfault! We recommend answers containing the solution itself instead of linking a possible solution.